# Intellisense Javascript doesn't work for scope variables (VS 2015 Web)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, paperjs

I want to use Paper.js with Intellisense, but it doesn't work, because all the functions are capsulated by a global variable and the Intellisense doesn't recognize it. When I use it in JetBrains WebStorm it works.

Here it doesn't work.

```
var point = new Point(10, 10);
```

And here it works:

```
var point = new paper.Point(10, 10);
```

Both solutions work in the browser, but just the second one gives me Intellisense support.

Is there a workaround for it?

Thank You!

Comment: You could have `var Point = paper.Point; var Path = paper.Path;` etc... at the beginning of your project... (this answer is not great so I just post it as a comment)

Comment: Thank you for your help...Hmm its funny, in every Tutorial they use just `new Point(10, 10)` and it works in the browser with no errors but the Intellisense can't resolve it.

Comment: I guess it's because Intellisense can't understand the paperjs language (which enables [operator overloading](http://scratchdisk.com/posts/operator-overloading)).

Comment: Yes, I'm with your opinion. Many thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define:

```
var Point = paper.Point; 
var Path = paper.Path; 
// etc...
```

at the beginning of your project.

Intellisense can't understand the paperjs language (which enables [operator overloading](http://scratchdisk.com/posts/operator-overloading)).